# RMySQL fails running multiple queries

Tags: r

The environment:
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
[1] RMySQL_0.10.9 DBI_0.4-1

Basically what I'm doing is getting whit a query a data.frame and then adding a column with sapply() running a function, but most of the time(some times work) I get this error:

```
Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'raw' Calls: getData ... dbClearResult -> dbIsValid -> dbIsValid -> .local -> .Call In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50) Execution halted
```

This is my code:

```
myFunc <- function(row){
  res <- dbGetQuery(conn,my_sub_query)
  return(res[1,1])
}

df <- dbGetQuery(conn,my_query)

df$newCol <- sapply( df$col1, myFunc)
```

Fails most of the time, please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the actual query `my_sub_query`?

Comment: There might be a possibility to combine both queries.

Comment: @Parfait no there is not a possibility to combine the queries

Comment: Can we see the magical queries? If from same database, there is an SQL way! If not, how are they migrated into same dataframe?